# Is $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ for $x \in [0,1]$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{a_n\}_0^\infty \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n| <\infty$. Is $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ for $x \in [0,1]$ uniformly convergent?

I believe it is. By Abel's uniform convergence test since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|$ converges and $x^n$ is monotonically decreasing on the set. Is this sound reasoning or is there another approach?

Comment: Yes. For another approach, take a look at [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test).

Comment: Using Abel's test here is not wrong, but seems to be a bit of an overkill. You can also directly write $f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n x^n$ and observe the result from here.

Comment: The Weierstrass M test.

Comment: @PedroM. How do you determine that the series converges uniformly by observing directly from what you've written?

Comment: We write $\left|f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n\right| = \left|\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n x^n\right| \leq \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |a_n|$, and then directly apply the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: @PedroM.Thanks, Pedro. Out of curiousity, can I also determine that $f(x)$ is continuous? It seems intuitively to me that it is, but I wonder how to show rigorously.

Comment: The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.